# swift - chaining UIView animation

Tags: swift, core-animation, calayer, uiviewanimation

I'd like to animate my `UIImageView` with these steps:

1. scale 2 times
2. **scaled** image movement

So I'm trying like this:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
   self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)                        
}) { _ in                        
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: -50, y: -50)
                        
   }) { _ in

        //other steps
   }
 }
```

But the result is that before moving `imageView` got back to previous size and then moving. How to move **scaled** `view`?

also I've tried to change layer's `anchorPoint` inside the `animate` block with no success

And maybe there is more simple way to achieve my goal: ability to zoom out image, then focus at 3 custom points, then zoom in to the initial size.

Comment: What kind of `focus at 3 custom points` do you want?

Comment: And what is your goal when you trying to change  layer's `anchorPoint`?

Comment: check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25397208/chaining-uiview-animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: Since you are assigning the `transform` to a new one without keeping the old configuration, so in your second animation, your view will transform to the default scale (1, 1). All you need is just assigning the `transform` to a new one which contains all the old configurations plus the new you want.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
  self.button.transform = self.button.transform.scaledBy(x: 2, y: 2)
}) { _ in
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
    self.button.transform = self.button.transform.translatedBy(x: -50, y: -50)
  }) { _ in
    
  }
}
```

It's even better if you use `animateKeyframes`

Comment: Thank you! Solved my problem! And for your comments - I need show specific quarter of the image, like top left for 3 sec, then top right for 2 sec, then back to the center and scale to 1. So I guess that changing `anchorPoint` is the better way for this? `animatedKeyFrames` is a goos advice, thank you

Comment: For the focus, I think the easiest way is just to calculate movement vector and then translate the view so that the point you want to be focused on is displayed in your desired area. No need to change the layer's `anchorPoint` in this case.

Comment: thanks for the answer. by the way, if there is any way to use .animateKeyFrames when I need to change imageView.image via UIView.transition block? or any other way? Because it looks pretty, but not for case with changing image (and time for changing every image is different, by the way)

Comment: What do you mean `imageView.image via UIView.transition block` ?

Comment: at some steps of my animation (about 20 times) I need to change image with fade effect, so I'm using `UIView.transition` for this. and times to show each image is different

Answer (score 7):

There are few approaches:

1. One approach is to put the start of an animation in the completion handler of the prior animation:

   ```swift
   UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
       …
   } completion: { _ in
       UIView.animate(withDuration: 2) { 
           …
       } completion: {  _ in 
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 1) { 
               …
           } completion: {  _ in 
               …
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. If you want to avoid a tower of nested animations (each in the completion handler of the prior one), you can use a keyframe animation, e.g. this is a five second animation with three separate keyframes, each with a duration of one third of the total, and whose start time is set accordingly:

   ```swift
   UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 5, delay: 0) { 
       UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1 / 3) {
           …
       }

       UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1 / 3, relativeDuration: 1 / 3) {
           …
       }

       UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2 / 3, relativeDuration: 1 / 3) {
           …
       }
   }
   ```

   The above is for Swift 5.3 and later. For earlier versions, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63649436/2) of this answer.
3. Nowadays, we might naturally reach for Swift concurrency (because it excels at managing dependencies between asynchronous tasks) and generally, Swift is pretty good at rendering `async` renditions of old Objective-C API with completion handler parameters (see [SE-0297: Concurrency Interoperability with Objective-C: Asynchronous completion-handler methods](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md#asynchronous-completion-handler-methods)). But the `UIView` animation functions are not (yet) elegantly mapped to `async` renditions. So we might just write our own `async` rendition of `UIView` animation API using a continuation:

   ```swift
   extension UIView {
       class func animate(
           for duration: Duration,
           delay: Duration = .zero,
           options: UIView.AnimationOptions = [],
           animations: @MainActor @Sendable @escaping () -> Void
       ) async {
           await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
               UIView.animate(
                   withDuration: duration.timeInterval,
                   delay: delay.timeInterval,
                   options: options,
                   animations: animations
               ) { _ in
                   continuation.resume()
               }
           }
       }
   }

   extension Duration {
       var timeInterval: TimeInterval {
           let (wholeSeconds, attoseconds) = components
           return TimeInterval(wholeSeconds) + TimeInterval(attoseconds) / 1e18
       }
   }
   ```

   Then, from an asynchronous context, you can use Swift concurrency:

   ```swift
   await UIView.animate(for: .seconds(1), delay: .seconds(1.5)) {
       …
   }
   await UIView.animate(for: .seconds(1)) {
       …
   }
   await UIView.animate(for: .seconds(1)) {
       …
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks for the answer. by the way, if there is any way to use `.animateKeyFrames` when I need to change `imageView.image `via `UIView.transition` block? or any other way? Because it looks pretty, but not for case with changing image (and time for changing every image is different, by the way)

Comment: That’s different from what was posed in the question. Am I inferring that you want to animate the changing of the image (e.g. with a cross dissolve or the like)? In that case, you’d use the first pattern, but rather than `UIView.animate(withDuration:animations:completion:)`, you’d use  [`UIView.transition(with:duration:options:animations:completion:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622574-transition).