# UICollectionView didSelectItemAt not working

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I need an animation when a collection view cell is tapped. I wrote an override function for it. But `UICollectionView didSelectItemAt` is not working when I override `touchesBegan` on the custom cell.

**ViewController**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.answersCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)
    self.selectedIndex = indexPath.item
}
```

**CustomCellClass**

```
public override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
    }
}

public override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    }
}

public override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) {
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    }
}
```

I want to animate the selection.

Comment: Have you tried delaysContentTouches = false?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619398-delayscontenttouches

Comment: 2. In every method try to call "super"; for example in `touchesBegan` add:   `super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)`

Comment: Is `answersCollectionView` a *different* collection view? If not, you are calling `.selectItem(at:...` inside `didSelectItemAt`, which doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote "I need an animation when a collection view cell is tapped...". If this is the only requirement you have, I would do this instead:

1. Make sure your collection view allows selection like so: `myCollectionView.allowsSelection = true`
2. Add a function to your CustomCell like so:

   ```
    class CustomCellClass: UICollectionViewCell {
    //configure the cell as you normally would

        /// animates cell after a selection
        func animateSelection() {
            //please note that this is the most basic way of animating
            //there are multiple other ways. check out the provided link below in the post
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) { 
                self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.9, y: 0.9)
            } completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.1) { 
                    self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
                }
            }
        }
    }
   ```
3. call this new function during `didSelectItemAt` callback.

   ```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        //you don't need to do this - the cell is already selected
        //self.answersCollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: .centeredHorizontally)

        if let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CustomCellClass {
            selectedCell.animateSelection()
        }

        //do other things you need to do in order to react to cell selection
        ..
    }
   ```

[Here is the exchange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63647652/swift-chaining-uiview-animation) that you can reference to see other animation techniques.